# Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object (middleware role authentication)

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware, roles, laravel-middleware

i want to make two authentication roles(admin and user). every thing work fine, but for example when i am logged as user and i try to access the admin dashboard i want want redirected to the user dashboard instead cause i must not have access to it as a user... the problem is when i try to access the admin dashboard as a user i get this error : `Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object`

this my two middlewares...

Admin middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'admin'){
        return $next($request);
    }else{
        redirect()->route('login');
    }
}
```

User middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'user'){
        return $next($request);
    }else{
        redirect()->route('login');
    }
}
```

and i did edit the RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware to this.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        /*if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }*/

        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->role == 'user') {
            return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
        }
        elseif (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->role == 'admin'){
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In middleware, it is important to handle all cases and `return` the redirects accordingly :

```
return redirect()->route('login');
```

Comment: thanks for mentioning that i just forgot the return... i took 1hour xD.

Answer (score 0):

You should return the redirect
Admin middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'admin'){
        return $next($request);
    }else{
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
}
```

User middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'user'){
        return $next($request);
    }else{
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
}
```